# How do I concatenate 2 bytes?

Tags: c#, byte

I have 2 bytes:

```
byte b1 = 0x5a;  
byte b2 = 0x25;
```

How do I get `0x5a25` ?

Answer (score 45):

It can be done using bitwise operators '<<' and '|'

```
public int Combine(byte b1, byte b2)
{
    int combined = b1 << 8 | b2;
    return combined;
}
```

Usage example:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    byte b1 = 0x5a;
    byte b2 = 0x25;
    var combine = Combine(b1, b2);
    Assert.That(combine, Is.EqualTo(0x5a25));
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain you didn't need to wrap that in a function :-) But you're right, so +1.

Comment: Beware of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness. It really matters what the bytes will be used for. Alhough most c# work is done on the Intel platform, the bytes may be send out as a part of network protocol where endiannes matters.

Comment: oh the OR is nice :-) but it is still short... 
+1 for the OR :)

Comment: Func<byte, byte, int> combine;


            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                combine = new Func<byte, byte, int>((i, j) => j << 8 | i);
            }
            else
            {
                combine = new Func<byte, byte, int>((i, j) => i << 8 | j);
            }

int result = combine(b1, b2);

Answer (score 18):

Using bit operators:
`(b1 << 8) | b2` or just as effective `(b1 << 8) + b2`

Answer (score 7):

A more explicit solution (also one that might be easier to understand and extend to byte to int i.e.):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Byte2Short {
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public byte lowerByte;
  [FieldOffset(1)]
  public byte higherByte;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public short Short;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = (new Byte2Short(){lowerByte = b1, higherByte = b2}).Short;
```

This lets the compiler do all the bit-fiddling and since Byte2Short is a struct, not a class, the new does not even allocate a new heap object ;)

Comment: maybe - but if you want to express that something can be understood more than one way on a bit-wise level it is the tool of choice. Personally I prefer the shift+or method, but it becomes quite cumbersome when your target is i.e. a uint64, while the union still remains very readable in that case.

Comment: There's also `BitConverter.ToUInt16(new[] { b2, b1, }, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte b1 = 0x5a;
byte b2 = 0x25;

Int16 x=0;

x= b1;
x= x << 8;
x +=b2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be

```
b1*256 + b2
```

Comment: (b1 << 8) + b2 will do the job faster.

Comment: @futureelite7, that's unlikely to be the case with modern compilers - in any case, you should have used (b1<<8)|b2 :-)

Comment: @futureelite7: I note that `b1*256+b2` has one fewer character than `(b1<<8)+b2` so actually `b1*256+b2` is faster. :-)

Comment: This is ridiculous. Both are practically the same.

running a trillion statments using: c = (a << 8) + b   stopping timer @ 00:00:00.7638591

running a trillion statments using: c = a << 8 | b    stopping timer @ 00:00:00.7634362
running a trillion statments using: c = a * 256 + b    stopping timer @ 00:00:00.8592438
a: 1  00000000000000000000000000000001
b: 15  00000000000000000000000000001111
c: 271  00000000000000000000000100001111

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous.

If a byte array you could simply:
byte[] myarray = new byte[2];
myarray[0] = b1;
myarray[1] = b2;
and you could serialize the byearray...

or if you're attempting to do something like stuffing these 16 bits into a int or similar you could learn your bitwise operators in c#...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

do something similar to:

`byte b1 = 0x5a;  byte b2 = 0x25; int foo = ((int) b1 << 8) + (int) b2;`

now your int foo = 0x00005a25.