# C#: storing 16 bit data

Tags: c#, twos-complement

I have written the following code in C# to get 16-bit twos compliment values over uart from 8 bit microcontroller. I am receiving data in bytes form. So I am combining the two bytes to form a 16-bit value. My issue is that my all values are becoming negative, but in reality some are negative some are not. Please tell me what is wrong of the following code that I am doing:

```
int t = 0;
int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
float  [] buffer2 = new float[bytes];
for(int i=0;t< buffer.Length;i++)
{
    buffer2[i]= ~(((buffer[t]<< 8) | buffer[t+1]) - 1);
    t = t + 2;
}
```

Comment: It seems you can do this a lot easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1935468/993547

Comment: And why use float?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg its 8 bit data from 8 bit microcontroller.as my actual data is 16 bit 2' compliment, so sending it in two parts over uart.as controller at a time can send 8 bit of data .

Comment: @PatrickHofman my actual value is in decimals so using float here to sore them

Comment: But are you sending it in the float data format then? If so, you can't just add them together.

Comment: Tell us what the input values are and what your expected outcome is.

Comment: If it's 2s-complement, you just need to shift and OR: `short result = (short)(lowByte | highByte << 8);`

Comment: @PatrickHofman for eg input values are `01`,`4c`.combining them 16 bit value will be `014c`, now as they are in 2's compliment form its binary will be `0000 0001 0100 1100`  as no is positive so decimal equivalent will be `+332`.

Comment: here instead of `+332` it is giving me `-332`

Comment: Did you test the code given in my first comment? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1935468/993547

Comment: @MatthewWatson typecasting it with short worked for me.m getting proper values.

Comment: @MatthewWatson in 8 bit controller i have to do this `~(((buffer[t]<< 8) | buffer[t+1]) - 1);` using c language.how here just typecasting `short` works ?can you explain me.